Replace a Do loop with a Map. (Nested Map)
I have a Do loop which has a Map inside of it. I would like to replace the loop with a Map creating a nested Map structure.
The initial code that does the job is:
rangeset[n_] := Range[0, n - 1];

m=2;

jof = {{1, 7}, {2, 7}};

mA = ConstantArray[{}, m];

Do[
  mA[[k]] = Plus @@@ Tuples[Map[(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(s = 1\), \(# - 
            1\)]\((jof[\([\)\(s, 2\)\(]\)])\)\)) rangeset[
         jof[[#, 2]]] &, Flatten@Position[jof, _List?(#[[1]] == k &)]]]
  , {k, 1, m}];

mA = Map[Sort, mA]; mA

(* Output is {{0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}} *)


I would like to convert the Do loop to using something like an outer Map but I cannot get this to work.
Now I have looked in the question archive about nesting Map or using Outer and Function or MapThread etc etc etc but to no avail.
I don't see how I can use the list iterator {k,1,m} as input to a Map where this value k is used inside the earlier Map.
I would think there is succinct way of doing this but I'm just not seeing it.
EDIT: A more complex example so it doesn't appear simplistic.
m=3;

jof = {{3, 13}, {2, 11}, {3, 5}, {2, 5}, {1, 23}};

(* previous code*)

(* output is *)

(*
{{0, 3575, 7150, 10725, 14300, 17875, 21450, 25025, 28600, 32175, 
  35750, 39325, 42900, 46475, 50050, 53625, 57200, 60775, 64350, 
  67925, 71500, 75075, 78650}, {0, 13, 26, 39, 52, 65, 78, 91, 104, 
  117, 130, 715, 728, 741, 754, 767, 780, 793, 806, 819, 832, 845, 
  1430, 1443, 1456, 1469, 1482, 1495, 1508, 1521, 1534, 1547, 1560, 
  2145, 2158, 2171, 2184, 2197, 2210, 2223, 2236, 2249, 2262, 2275, 
  2860, 2873, 2886, 2899, 2912, 2925, 2938, 2951, 2964, 2977, 
  2990}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 143, 144, 145, 
  146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 286, 287, 288, 
  289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 429, 430, 431, 
  432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 572, 573, 574, 
  575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584}}
*)

EDIT2:
I just came up with as a solution.
Subscript[L, j] = 
  Table[Flatten@Position[jof, _List?(#[[1]] == k &)], {k, 1, m}];

Apply[Plus, Tuples /@ Map[Sum[(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(s = 1\), \(l - 
          1\)]\((jof[\([s, 2]\)])\)\)) rangeset[
       jof[[l, 2]]], {l, {#}}] &, Subscript[L, j], {2}], {2}]
```


If you simply want to replace the Do loop with a Map, following might help
Map[ k |-> Plus @@@      Tuples[      Map[       Product[(jof[[s, 2]]), {s, 1, # - 1}] rangeset[jof[[#, 2]]] &       , Flatten@Position[jof, _List?(#[[1]] == k &)]]] // Sort    , Range[1, m]]

@vindobona That works. Thanks for the effort. I also came up with my own as well.

rangeset[n_] := Range[0, n - 1];
m = 3;
jof = {{3, 13}, {2, 11}, {3, 5}, {2, 5}, {1, 23}};

mA = Sort[
    Total /@ 
     Tuples[Times @@ jof[[1 ;; # - 1, 2]]*rangeset[jof[[#, 2]]] & /@ 
       Flatten@Position[jof, {#, _}]]] & /@ Range[m]


{{0, 3575, 7150, 10725, 14300, 17875, 21450, 25025, 28600, 32175, 
  35750, 39325, 42900, 46475, 50050, 53625, 57200, 60775, 64350, 
  67925, 71500, 75075, 78650}, {0, 13, 26, 39, 52, 65, 78, 91, 104, 
  117, 130, 715, 728, 741, 754, 767, 780, 793, 806, 819, 832, 845, 
  1430, 1443, 1456, 1469, 1482, 1495, 1508, 1521, 1534, 1547, 1560, 
  2145, 2158, 2171, 2184, 2197, 2210, 2223, 2236, 2249, 2262, 2275, 
  2860, 2873, 2886, 2899, 2912, 2925, 2938, 2951, 2964, 2977, 
  2990}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 143, 144, 145, 
  146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 286, 287, 288, 
  289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 429, 430, 431, 
  432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 572, 573, 574, 
  575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584}}


Nice. I came up with once of my own that I am about to add to the question.

Using the function notation to do the outer map:
(k |-> Plus @@@ Tuples[Map[(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(s = 1\), \(# - 
            1\)]\((jof[\([s, 2]\)])\)\)) rangeset[
                  jof[[#, 2]]] &, 
      Flatten@Position[jof, _List?(#[[1]] == k &)]]]) /@ Range[2]

(result: {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42}})

Oh, it looks like @vindobona already indicated this as answer in a comment before this answer.
